# How make a Range between two float lists in python?

Tags: python, arrays, list, range, increment

There are two lists.

The same number of elements (floats).

A int variable to have the number of steps.

Is there a command or a order is able to make a range from the first values to the second ones?

```
divider = 12
startValues= [0.9,     0.3,     0.8,     0.9]
endValues  = [0.6,     1.0,     1.0,     0.4]

#the result should look like this:
#incrementalValues = [0.025, 0.05833, 0.0166, 0.04166]

#startValues =     [0.9,   0.3,     0.8,    0.9     ]
#intermediaryVal = [0.875, 0.35833, 0.8166, 0.85834 ]
#intermediaryVal = [0.85,  0.4166,  0.8333, 0.81668 ]
#intermediaryVal = [0.825, 0.4749,  0.8500, 0.77502 ]
#intermediaryVal = [0.8,   0.5333,  0.8666, 0.73336 ]
#intermediaryVal = [0.775, 0.5916,  0.8833, 0.6917  ]
#intermediaryVal = [0.75,  0.6499,  0.9000, 0.65004 ]
#intermediaryVal = [0.725, 0.7083,  0.9166, 0.60838 ]
#intermediaryVal = [0.7,   0.7666,  0.9333, 0.56672 ]
#intermediaryVal = [0.675, 0.8249,  0.9500, 0.52506 ]
#intermediaryVal = [0.65,  0.8833,  0.9666, 0.4834  ]
#intermediaryVal = [0.625, 0.9416,  0.9833, 0.44174 ]
#endValues =       [0.6,   1.0,     1.0,    0.4     ]
```

Comment: So your question is how to make a range that goes from, for example, 0.9 to 0.6, taking the 12 steps defined by the integer?

Comment: yes. this is exactly that.

Comment: I don't see many Python idiomatics involved. This is boring low-level stuff with usual rounding due to float issues.

Comment: Simply use numpy.linspace(0.9,0.6,13) for instance

Comment: Non-numpy: `incrementalValues  = [(x[0]-x[1])/divider for x in zip(startValues,endValues)]`

Comment: There is no code in your [mre] that accomplishes anything - hence we can not be sure where your errors are. What did you try to do to make happen what you need to happen?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use numpy

```
import numpy as np 
  
spaces = list(np.linspace(0.5, 1.5, 8))
print(spaces)

# output :
# [0.5, 0.64285714285714279, 0.7857142857142857, 0.9285714285714286, 1.0714285714285714, 1.2142857142857142, 1.3571428571428572, 1.5]
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple function could be this one (maybe the name is a bit unlucky):

```py
def listRange(startValues, endValues, divider):
    steps = [(e-s)/divider for s,e in zip(startValues, endValues)]
    for t in range(1,divider+1):
        yield [v+s*t for v,s in zip(startValues,steps)]
```

the usage is like the `range` function:

```py
divider = 12
startValues= [0.9,     0.3,     0.8,     0.9]
endValues  = [0.6,     1.0,     1.0,     0.4]

for v in listRange(startValues, endValues, divider):
    print(v)
```

Comment: I think I will you the fonction. it can work on any machine.

Answer (score 1):

i use np.arange

```
divider = 12
startValues= [0.9,     0.3,     0.8,     0.9]
endValues  = [0.6,     1.0,     1.0,     0.4]

lst = []
for start , stop in zip(startValues , endValues):
    if start<stop:
        step =(stop-start) / divider
    else:
        step = -(start - stop) / divider
    lst.append(np.arange(start , stop ,step))

pd.DataFrame(lst).T
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(lst).T , pd.DataFrame([endValues])])
```

[image]